# USB-C Hub Ethernet Not Working

Tags: networking, usb, ethernet, chrome-book

Today I installed Ubuntu 18.04.3 on a [Google Pixel Chromebook (2015)](https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/6164568?hl=en) using the [MrChromebox firmware script](https://mrchromebox.tech/#fwscript). The installation went well but there seems to be a problem with my [USB-C Hub with ethernet adapter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07NKB697F). Ubuntu is not recognizing the ethernet port on the adapter. I know it works because, before I installed Ubuntu, I tried it on ChromeOS.

Any advice on getting Ubuntu to recognize the ethernet port on this USB-C adapter?

Thank you!

Edit: output of `lsusb` command as recommended by @telcoM:

With USB-C Hub disconnected:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 8087:07dc Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

With USB-C Hub connected:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 8087:07dc Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 013: ID 1d5c:7102  
Bus 001 Device 012: ID 1a40:0801 Terminus Technology Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 011: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. 4-port hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Please run `lsusb` with the USB-C hub unplugged, then plug it in and run `lsusb` again. Compare the outputs and edit the line or lines added when you plug in the hub into your question. The `ID:xxxx:yyyy` values may allow someone to identify the chip used to implement the ethernet functionality of the hub and determine which driver module would be needed for it.

Comment: @telcoM : thanks! I included the output of the `lsusb` command.

Answer (score 3):

Partial answer:

If you look only at the additional devices as suggested in the comment, you see

```
Bus 001 Device 011: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. 4-port hub
```

a 4-port hub, and on this hub two devices

```
Bus 001 Device 012: ID 1a40:0801 Terminus Technology Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 013: ID 1d5c:7102
```

with no further information. From your Amazon link, your "hub" includes a HDMI device, a card reader, and the ethernet adapter.

So we must somehow find out which of those two listed USB devices corresponds to which of the three devices you should have. (Guess: The HDMI device probably uses alternate mode, so it's the other two).

You can do that either by `lsusb -v -d 1a40:0801` and `lsusb -v -d 1d5c:7102`, which should give you the class, or by looking at `dmesg` after you plug in the hub, and the kernel hopefully identifies the card reader. (If you don't know how to interpret the `dmesg` output, please include it in your question. You can indent four spaces for pre-formatted text like log outputs.)

Normally googling for `1a40:0801` and `1d5c:7102` can be used to get more information, but in both cases I couldn't find anything.

The most likely case is that your Ubuntu is for some reason missing the kernel drivers needed for the USB ethernet adapter.